# Converting JavaScript from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8 standards

Tags: 8, javascript, migrations

I have a Drupal 7 module that contains a JavaScript file whose only contents are

```
Drupal.behaviors.InitializeMapplic = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    jQuery("#mapplic").mapplic(Drupal.settings.mapplic);
  }
};
```

I'm aware that Drupal 8 introduced a new JavaScript API and that this code needs to be updated. However, I'm confused as to what the Drupal 8 equivalent is. I have read and tried to dissect the change records at https://www.drupal.org/node/1793334 and I have reviewed the API documentation at https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview.

So my question is, exactly what needs to change here in order for this to play ball with Drupal 8? Will it just become

```
jQuery("#mapplic").mapplic(drupalSettings.mapplic);
```

all by itself or what? Any light that can be shed on this for me would be appreciated.

Comment: So what was your result after you reviewed https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview? Search the mentioned link for "A really basic example", apply that on your code, done. How did you came to think it would look like `jQuery("#mapplic").mapplic(drupalSettings.mapplic);`?

Comment: You already linked the answer in your question, so I have to flag this question as "unclear what you are asking".

Comment: Should be passing jquery in and using $.

Comment: @leymannx Perhaps I was doing something incorrectly before because when I applied the changes, I was not getting different any results. I'm going to try to follow the guide again and I will post feedback.

Answer (score 0):

As you already linked from the docs https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview I just repeat the most important parts here:

**MYMODULE.libraries.yml**

```
foobar:
  js:
    js/foobar.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.once
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupalSettings
```

**js/foobar.js**

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myModuleBehavior = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('.MYSELECTOR', context).once('myCustomBehavior').each(function () {
        // Apply the myCustomBehaviour effect to the elements only once.

        // I guess you have to pass something to `settings` first.
        // $("#mapplic").mapplic(settings.mapplic);

        console.log('Hello world!');
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

**MYMODULE.module**

```
function MYMODULE_page_attachments_alter(array &$attachments) {
  $attachments['#attached']['library'][] =  'MYMODULE/foobar';
}
```

---

Update: removed some flaws.

Comment: So, following this, all it did was cause two fatal errors due to exhausting all of the memory allowed, and then threw an unknown exception before bursting into flames. Perhaps this js file is not doing what I thought it was and that is why my question seemed unclear in direction.

Comment: This code didn't do that @GL007 (unless you've introduced a duplicate function name or something) - as it happens, this code (the PHP side) is a no-op. `$variables` should be `$attachments`. But it still wouldn't throw an exception. What is the exception exactly?

Comment: Perhaps I should explain a little more. This D7 module that I'm upgrading gives the ability to use a svg plugin called Mapplic. You place a block, the block has the libraries attached to it. The plugin is dependent upon the JQuery Mapplic library. I am 99% certain that I have everything from the D7 module carried over into Drupal 8, and all of the functions work, but I'm very confused at this point on how to actually tie it all together into the custom block. I thought this Javascript file was what was prevent that, but apparently not.

Comment: "carried over into Drupal 8" meaning that I have already have the code working in Drupal 8.

Comment: Is that a custom block you've coded?

Comment: @Clive Yes, it is. More specifically, I generated the plugin with Drupal Console. In the block, I only have it attaching some markup and then now utilizing #attached to link in the libraries. I have only begun custom module development a few weeks ago, and I don't have my mind wrapped around every little concept quite yet. Even after analyzing the Drupal 7 code, it is not clear to me how the functions I have that do the bulk of the work, including generating a json response that should be handed off to the JQuery library to generate this map, actually know to put it all into my block.